# History of the "Square Root of 2"

Tags: mathematics

I came across the following article on the "square root of two":

[image]

Based on this, I had the following questions:

- **Does anyone know why the Babylonians were interested in the square root of two? Perhaps there might have been some application related to engineering or measuring materials that required them to calculate the square root of two?**
- And does anyone know how exactly the above number approximation was calculated? How did they decide to add 24/60, 51/60^2, 10/60^3 etc.?

Thanks!

**Reference:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2

Comment: Babylonian mathematical sources typically provide examples rather than algorithmic specifications. There is a method of computing square roots known as the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method). I am not up to date on the latest scholarship regarding strength of evidence that the Babylonians actually used it. Fractions with power-of-60 denominators are just a natural consequence of performing numerical computations in a sexagesimal system, which we know is what the Babylonians used.

Comment: David Fowler and Eleanor Robson, "Square Root Approximations in Old Babylonian Mathematics: YBC 7289 in Context," *Historia Mathematica* **25** (1998), 366–378: 
"We consider several aspects of the role and evaluation of the four-sexagesimal-place approximation to $\sqrt{2}$ on the well-known Old Babylonian tablet YBC 7289. By referring to what is known about OB school texts, we show that this text is most probably a school exercise by a trainee scribe who got the approximation from a coefficient list. These coefficient lists are briefly described, with their use in geometrical problems."

Comment: thank you both for your comments! So the "square root of 2" would have come up naturally come up in the sexagesimal system?

Comment: $\sqrt{2}$ comes up naturally as the length of the diagonal of the unit square. School exercises do not have to have practical relevance, they can be abstract (as the authors of the cited article think is the case for this clay tablet). One could imagine all kind of practical uses for square roots in general such as sizing rectangular storage facilities or in surveying irregularly shaped pieces of land. I don't have an overview of clay tablets that involve practical problems solved via square roots.

Comment: You might be interested in the following book: David Flannery, [**The Square Root of 2. A Dialogue Concerning a Number and a Sequence**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/038720220X), Copernicus Books, 2006, xii + 256 pages (MR 2006j:00002; [Zbl 1146.00003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1146.00003)). ([Review](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-square-root-of-2-a-dialogue-concerning-a-number-and-a-sequence)) Incidentally, the author's name might ring a bell. A while back his daughter was extensively written about in magazines and newspapers for [this project](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1565123778).